# Отмена действия при повторном нажатии

Tags: javascript

Как отменить действие при повторном нажатии?

```
document.querySelector(".menu").onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам решение )
Данным способом вы сможете нажать на элемент только один раз до перезагрузки страницы

```js
document.querySelector(".menu").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}, {once: true});
```

```html
<div class="menu">1234567890</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо именно повторно кликать для вызова действия (отмены) чего-либо, можно сделать так.

```js
var flag = false;
document.querySelector(".menu").onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  flag = true;
}
if(flag){
  //Код. Например
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: `flag = !flag` тогда уж

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Почему? Надо же при повторном клике выполнить что-то

Comment: Я так понимаю, человек хочет обычный на 2 состояния. Нажал 1 раз - одно, второй раз - другое, третий раз - снова первое. Поэтому флаг просто с true на false меняется, и обратно

Comment: @VladimirGonchar А, если так то можно и переделать

Answer (score 0):

Если конкретно с Вашим примером
При каждом клике проверяем текущее значение `style.overflow`
Если оно не равно `hidden`, установить `hidden`, иначе `auto`

```js
document.querySelector(".menu").onclick = function() {
  const target = document.body.style;
  target.overflow = target.overflow !== "hidden" ? "hidden" : "auto";
}
```

Вместо [Условного оператора](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#uslovnyy-operator) можете использовать что-то подобное:

```js
if (document.body.style.overflow === "hidden")
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
else
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```